# Qt Installer Framework - Update control script

Tags: qt, installation, updates, auto-update, qt-installer

**The problem**

I have a Qt IFW installer with an online repository, from which users fetch data to install and update the software.

My installer has a "root script" defined in `config.xml`:

```xml
<Installer>
    <!-- ... -->
    <ControlScript>controllerscript.qs</ControlScript>
</Installer>
```

Now I want to change the content of `controllerscript.qs` and deploy it on the online repository.

- when a new user installs the software for the first time, it works as expected
- when a user updates its software from a previous version using `MaintenanceTool.exe`, it *does not* get the update

**Possible solution**

I realized that when you create the installer, it generates a file named `MaintenanceTool.dat` which seems to contain `controllerscript.qs` (+ other things). I managed to manually copy that file and push it to the online repository (inside a package). That way, the maintenance tool is able to see the package update, and correctly gets the new `MaintenanceTool.dat`. After that, the maintenance tool is indeed using the new code from `controllerscript.qs`.

**Question**

- Is there another (cleaner) way to achieve that?
- If not, is it really safe to provide a manual update to `MaintenanceTool.dat`? That file contains many other things, so is there a risk to interfere with the rest?

Thanks,

Comment: I'm wondering if Qt IFW refers to Qt Installer Framework

Comment: Yes it does - that's the "official" abbreviation (see for example: https://www.qt.io/blog/qt-installer-framework-4.0-released)